# If Date Is In Range Return Value

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am stuck with what it seems should be an easy thing to do. I want to look up a date in a range of dates and return a value. See below an example.

[image]

Based on the value in column "G", I want it to return the value of column "A". The formula that I am using is:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:$B$8<=G2)/($C$2:$C$8>=G2),$A$2:$A$8)
```

However, this only returns the correct value for G2, but for G3 it is not working. Anyone has any advise on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

IF one has the Dynamic Formula `FILTER()`

```
=@FILTER(A:A,(B:B<=G2)*(C:C>=G2))
```

IF not then use:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($B$2:$B$8)/(($B$2:$B$8<=G2)*($C$2:$C$8>=G2)),1))
```